# Ubuntu 23.04 - gjs gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com/ding.js

Tags: gnome-shell-extension

I see this process in `htop`

```
gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com/ding.js -E -P usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com/ding.js
```

rastersoft.com is a website from Vigo-Spain. Do you have any idea what could be this?

Answer (score 2):

The `htop` output says it has something to do with one of your gnome shell extensions. [GJS](https://gjs.guide/about/) (Gnome JavaScript) is a programming environment similar to Node.js. Gnome Shell and pretty much all the extensions are written in javascript if I'm not mistaken.

It appears to be [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2087/desktop-icons-ng-ding/) that adds icons to the desktop. Main website is [here](https://www.rastersoft.com/programas/ding.html).

So it looks like the "rastersoft.com" part is just the name of the publisher of the extension and not a website that something is connecting to and "ding" is the name of the extension.

---

If you run the following command to list all files in your `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/` directory, you should see multiple directories that all follow the same extension-name@publisher format:

```
ls /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
```

---

In the future, there are a couple of ways you can identify the package that contains a file on your system.

The first option is to use the `apt-file` command. First, install the application:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apt-file
```

Next, update your file list:

```
sudo apt-file update
```

Finally, search for your file:

```
apt-file search /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com/ding.js
```

This should list the package name `gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng` as the package that contains the file.

Also, you can **search the contents of a package** for filenames at [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) and for this, we would need to search for **ding.js** and don't forget to set the distribution to **Kinetic**.

[Here is a link to the result.](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=ding.js&mode=exactfilename&suite=kinetic&arch=any)

[image]